# Why does the last array element print the array size?

Tags: arrays, c

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int f(int a, int b){
    if(a > 8 || a<0){
        printf("?\n");
        b = 2;
    }else if(b != 1){
        b= 1;
    }else{
        b = 2;
    }

    return b;
} 

int main(){
    int position[8];
    int currentPosition;
    int loopNumber;
    int loopNumber2;
    for(loopNumber = 0;loopNumber <= 8; loopNumber++){
        position[loopNumber] = -1;
        printf("%d\n", position[loopNumber]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &currentPosition);
    //printf("%d\n",f(currentPosition, position[currentPosition]));
    position[currentPosition] = f(currentPosition, position[currentPosition]);
    for(loopNumber2 = 0;loopNumber2 <= 8; loopNumber2++){
        printf("%d\n", position[loopNumber2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I get:

```
*-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
**0 (my input)**
1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
8*
```

Why does it print the 8 at the end? The 8th element printed -1 the first time but after I called my function it prints the array size?

Comment: With `int position[8]`, accessing `position[8]` is out of bound access, so UB.

Comment: `loopNumber2 <= 8` -> `loopNumber2 < 8`, or in C++11 *for range*: `for (auto e : position){ printf("%d\n", e); }`

Comment: off by 1 problem, int position[8] has valid entries position[0] to position[7] only. Stdio.h indicates this is a "c" question not "c++"

Comment: What you call the "8th" element is actually the 9th, but there are only eight of them.

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Answer (score 0):

Storing into the non-existing position[8] as you do is undefined behaviour. When you have undefined behaviour, anything can happen. Whatever happens is correct as far as the C language is concerned, whether you like it or not.

"Why?" is irrelevant. It's your fault, your fault alone, you deal with it. Fix your code.

Comment: I thought an array with the index 8 had 9 elements because it starts from 0, but i was writing to index 9 not the 9th element. I understand 

Comment: index 0 is the first element so index 8 is the ninth.